# Same predicate with same number of arguments, but different arguments type

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate that takes these arguments:
predicate(X, Y).
predicate(X, (Y, Z)).
(Second parameter can be an atom or a pair). Is it possible to do this only by pattern matching?

Comment: Should the first version be used *only* when `Y` isn't a pair?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify that a parameter is atomic using just pattern matching; you'd need a predicate to test for this.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I used atom predicate to check if it an atom.